# Exploit.Win32.CVE-2010-2568.gen malware detected

Tags: malware, exploit

I am not very good with computers. Actually, I am very bad :( so if you are willing to answer my question, could you please explain your answer in very simple terms, like to a complete dummy? Thanks in advance! :)

Also, if this is not the right place to ask this question, maybe you could tell me where I should post it?

I used free Kaspersky Security Scan and it came back with "problems found." Apparently, I have Exploit.Win32.CVE-2010-2568.gen attached to one of the System Volume Information files.

Since my computer has been hacked in the past, I kind of freaked out.

I used:

1. Malwarebytes
2. Panda Cloud Cleaner
3. Yet Another Cleaner
4. Avast
5. Microsoft Security Essentials

But nothing helps me to get rid of it. Is there something I could do? Also, could you please tell me if there is a good free antivirus/antimalware that can take care of it? Or should I purchase an antivirus program? I have Windows XP. I know, I know, time is running out...

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the fate for XP has been sealed and the bad guys have already started :(. I find most AV's are trivial to bypass and commonly only catch Un-targeted attacks. It could also be a false positive if you have a couple of AV's installed as sometimes these cause chaos with each other due to signatures and such. [Malwarebytes](http://www.theinquirer.net/inquirer/news/2335964/malwarebytes-offers-windows-xp-security-support-before-microsofts-april-deadline) has announced they will do their best to keep XP user's safe past April the 8th but i am dubious already due to the security of the system before! I would reccomend a [Linux](http://www.ubuntu.com/) ditro such as ubuntu which is a lot simpler to install and use than you may think but that is the only thing i can suggest for your peace of mind come april 8th. Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much! I am sorry I cannot give you any upvotes since I logged in as a guest.

Comment: Do you think I should panic about this malware thing though or just let it be?

Comment: I am scared of Linux, I never used it. I hate Macs, although I have one.

Comment: Many people are my friend. That is what happens after all these years of windows haha. You can even try it before you install it on a live cd, and if you wish you can even just boot off that everytime. Incase you still need windows then you can also dual boot linux and windows which is also relatively easy, in order to minimize the risks of using XP as your one and only OS :).

Comment: Something weird is happening because my malware virus just disappeared. Scary.

Comment: Hmm its probably hiding deep in the system files. I would'nt trust the system ... maybe a little after a fresh install.